# JSF PropertyNotFound Exception on Tomcat 6 outside of Eclipse

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, el

I have an app that runs perfectly on tomcat 6 in eclipse. When I take this app and manually deploy it to that same tomcat server outside of eclipse and run it, I get `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException` when trying to access many of the pages.

How can i get a `PropertyNotFoundException` when running an app outside of eclipse, but not in eclipse?

Stacktrace when trying to access a page:

```
Aug 28, 2013 9:40:30 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/ccadmin/publications/search.xhtml]
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ccadmin/publications/search.xhtml @107,92 value="#{pubBacker.beginYear}": Property 'beginYear' not found on type com.ccadmin.backing.PublicationBacker
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:170)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:284)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.SelectOneRenderer.getValues(SelectOneRenderer.java:46)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:74)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:65)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:279)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:237)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:127)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1819)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:447)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Aug 28, 2013 9:40:30 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl throwIt
INFO: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ccadmin/publications/search.xhtml @107,92 value="#{pubBacker.beginYear}": Property 'beginYear' not found on type com.ccadmin.backing.PublicationBacker
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:170)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:284)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.SelectOneRenderer.getValues(SelectOneRenderer.java:46)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:74)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:65)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:279)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:237)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:127)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1819)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:447)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: How did you move to tomcat outside of eclipse? Are you sure you took the most recent class files?

Comment: Well, apparently build of WAR failed and/or you're not running the code you think you're running?

Comment: I get no errors when building the war with maven install in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ccadmin/publications/search.xhtml @107,92 value="#{pubBacker.beginYear}": Property 'beginYear' not found on type com.ccadmin.backing.PublicationBacker`
 clearly specifies it is missing `beginYear` property for `pubBacker` bean.

Check if jar is updated. It is common mistake, at least for me. Some part of code is updated, but jar is not updated(`mvn install`).

Comment: I'm not sure how to check if the war file is updated. It builds just fine in eclipse with `maven install`

Comment: There were some .class files that were in my WEB-INF directory that must have gotten committed to the repo from someone else and they must have been overwritting the new .class files that got created with the same name.